# Remove arrays that contain only special characters

Tags: php

How can I remove all elements from an array that contain only special characters (such as ., * etc...).

Comment: You're going to need to give us more context.

Comment: Try [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter)

Comment: For example: $test[0]==1,$test[1]==hello,$test[2]== *.- I would like to automatically remove the array $test[2] as it contains specal characters,I do not know how to implement array_filter in this case :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function only_specialchars($string) {
    if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9]/i", $string)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

$filtered = array_filter($array, "only_specialchars"));
```

Something like this? This will filter all words that do **not** contain characters or numbers.